# Javascript onclick change attritube change localstorage

Tags: javascript, onclick

I have this script, where I need it to with  onclick on "button "change image from default to 2nd and add a counter / intervel when it runs out change the image to a 3rd image, and when clicked again go back to the 2nd image again and restart the timer. It needs to be saved in local storage, and it should be okay. I found some help this far, but now I cannot get it to change my img src on button onclick. Can anybody help, please?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  function aktivereSkift(initImagePath = null, initNextImagePath = null, count = 5) {

    if (initImagePath === null || initNextImagePath === null) {
      return false;
    }
    $(this).attr("src", initImagePath);

    let timer = count * 1000;
    let counter = setInterval(timer, 1000);

    function timer() {
      count = count - 1;

      localStorage.setItem('counter', count);
      if (count <= 0) {
        clearInterval(counter);
        return;
      }
    }
    setTimeout(() => $(this).attr('src', initNextImagePath), timer);

    localStorage.setItem('imagepath', initImagePath);
    localStorage.setItem('nextimagepath', initNextImagePath);
  }

  function loadDefaultValues() {
    const initImagePath = localStorage.getItem('imagepath');
    const initNextImagePath = localStorage.getItem('nextimagepath');
    const counter = localStorage.getItem('counter');
    aktivereSkift(initImagePath, initNextImagePath, counter);
  }

  loadDefaultValues();

  $(".toilet").on("click", () => {
    aktivereSkift('/lib/pictures/toiletBegyndt.png', '/lib/pictures/toiletSlut.png');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="toilet" src="~/lib/pictures/toilet.png" style="height:150px;width:150px;" />
```

Comment: I made a snippet with your updated code, and if you run it, you'll see this error : `Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'timer' has already been declared`. You are declaring `let timer` and then `function timer`, you can't do that. Didn't you catch this error in your console?

Comment: wow thats cool, well in visual studio it runs without any errors, other then the functionality not working...wich timer should i remove then? and thanks in advance ill try

Comment: but i still cant seem to get it to change pictures? even if i change names og remove one of the timers? pls help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK here's a working snippet, I hope it does what you want. LocalStorage doesn't work in a snippet (for security), just uncomment all the localStorage things :

```js
function aktivereSkift(
    initImagePath = null,
    initNextImagePath = null,
    count = 5
) {
    console.log("clicked =", this);

    if (initImagePath === null || initNextImagePath === null) {
        return false;
    }
    $(this).attr("src", initImagePath);

    let timer = count * 1000;
    let counter = setInterval(timerLS.bind(this, count), 1000);

    function timerLS() {
        count = count - 1;

        // localStorage.setItem("counter", count); --> Doesn't work in a Stackoverflow snippet

        if (count <= 0) {
            clearInterval(counter);
            return;
        }
    }
    setTimeout(() => $(this).attr("src", initNextImagePath), timer);

    // localStorage.setItem("imagepath", initImagePath);
    // localStorage.setItem("nextimagepath", initNextImagePath);
}

function loadDefaultValues() {
    const initImagePath = localStorage.getItem("imagepath");
    const initNextImagePath = localStorage.getItem("nextimagepath");
    const counter = localStorage.getItem("counter");
    aktivereSkift(initImagePath, initNextImagePath, counter);
}

// loadDefaultValues(); --> LocalStorage doesn't work inside a Stackoverflow snippet

$(".toilet").on("click", function () {
    aktivereSkift.call(
        this,
        "https://picsum.photos/200",
        "https://picsum.photos/200?grayscale"
    );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="toilet" src="https://picsum.photos/200" style="height:150px;width:150px;" />
```

Comment: cool i actually finally made it work, but maybe my understanding of local storage is wrong..with this script i thought that if the page was refreshed og closed i could revisit it and it would get lets say if it was en the 3rd image then it would know that and show it again, and also with the timer, that i would kinda "pause" if closed at then it would start again when the page is revisited.. is that wrong?

Comment: No, sounds about right. LocalStorage stores a string in the browser, that persists when you reload the page. However, all script gets reloaded, so the timer will start over again.

Answer (score 0):

The `this` keyword refers to the inner function where `this` keyword was declared. In that case `this` refers to the function not the `img` element.

```js
$("#img").attr("src", theImagePath);
```

Comment: I think you found the problem (wrong `this` context), but that's not the solution. How do you know there's a `#img` element? What if there's more than one image, which one to change? You need to bind the current `this` context to the callback function.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but in unfortunately not able to do this on my own, is it possible that you can make a quick example where i can see what you mean? im very new to this.. thanks in advance

Comment: That's just an example.